# Exapandable GridLayout RecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager, nestedrecyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

[As shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsWqd.jpg)

I want to make similar expandable GridLayout RecyclerView.

1. Initially, there will be a RecyclerView, which will contains Grid Laytout structure with span count=2.
2. When I click any Item of the grid, it will exapand a layout below that item, like in image and child layout will then again contain a RecyclerView to display child items.

How I can achive this.

I have tried some libraries like FlexboxLayoutManager but it doesn't show the desired results.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.